# Collate NoCase returning an Error

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using PySpark and the SQL Context which allows you to write SQL query within your framework. For some reason this command isn't working and am not sure why.

```
complaint_by_city = sqlContext.sql('SELECT City, COUNT(*) as `city_comp` '
                                   'FROM c311 '
                                   'GROUP BY City '
                                   'COLLATE NOCASE '
                                   'ORDER BY -city_comp '
                                   'LIMIT 21 ')
```

Edit the error it gives me is this

```
ParseException: u"\nmismatched input 'COLLATE' expecting {<EOF>, ',', '.', '[', 'LIMIT', 'OR', 'AND', 'IN', NOT, 'BETWEEN', 'LIKE', RLIKE, 'IS', 'ASC', 'DESC', 'WINDOW', EQ, '<=>', '<>', '!=', '<', LTE, '>', GTE, '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', 'DIV', '&', '|', '^', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE'}(line 1, pos 81)\n\n== SQL ==\nSELECT City, COUNT(*) as `city_comp` FROM c311 GROUP BY City ORDER BY -city_comp COLLATE NOCASELIMIT 21 \n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^\n"
```

Comment: First and fast guess: COLLATE NOCASE is not standard SQL. Most probably Spark SQL doesn't understand it. I would just take it out and retry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could I suggest:

```
SELECT LOWER(City) as City, COUNT(*) as city_comp
FROM c311
GROUP BY LOWER(City)
ORDER BY city_comp DESC
LIMIT 21;
```